# Make pry to skip rails and other gems code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, pry

I want to use pry-debugger gem for understanding others people code (rails mostly).
Usually I call binding.pry, then `skip`-ing repeatedly and watching code it outputs. 
Is there a way to make pry skip rails(and other gems) code and show me only local code in rails app directory?
I`ve tried something like this:

```
while(_dir_ =~ /.rvm/) do step end
while(_dir_ =~ /.rvm/) do _pry_.eval('step') end
_pry_.eval "while(_dir_ =~ /.rvm/) do _pry_.eval('step') end"
```

But it didn`t work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't skip Rails code using pry, by default. One way to get around this is to use add breakpoints to jump through different points in your application code.

[pry-debugger](https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger) has a number of `break` options, eg:

```
break app/models/user.rb:15    Break at line 15 in user.rb.
break 14                       Break at line 14 in the current file.
```

Hope this helps!